# Google authenticator expiration time (or drift?)

Tags: ruby, google-authenticator

I'm using a gem to enable google's multi factor authentication for my app. https://github.com/jaredonline/google-authenticator

We want to start using text messages to make this a bit more accessible, and I was wondering if anyone knew if you could control the expiration of the tokens? Would bumping the drift up to 300 seconds work? Just curious if anyone else has encountered this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes.

You can't change the length of a GA token (must be 30 seconds) but the drift will let you set a window for how much older a token can be.  The underlying ROTP library will compute all tokens over the time window and succeed if any match.

But you probably don't want a window that high.  The security comes from the user and the site being (mostly) in sync.  You should account for a bit of drift between your server and the user's device, but anything much more than ~30 seconds is going to mostly be to your users' detriment.  It's a 6 digit number -- it shouldn't take 5 minutes to key in.